# how to implements web-sockets in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, websocket, flex4

am developing a application by using java & flex with HTTP service every thing is work fine.
but i have a chatting requirement for this am using web-sockets in java it is also working.

my question is how implement web-sockets connection in flex and how pass data flex to java and how to get data from java to flex?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. This is the Websocket (RFC 6455) implementation in AS3.

https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket